# How can I find out without using AUTOCONF exactly what specifier (if any) is supported by a C compiler: inline, __inline__ or __inline?

Tags: c, inline, autoconf

Our project uses a lot of small one-line inline functions for simple  arithmetical calculations. How can we find out exactly what inline specifier is used by user's C compiler: `inline`, `__inline` or `__inline__`?

We looked at how GLIB library does it. The fragment is given below:

```
/* inlining hassle. for compilers that don't allow the `inline' keyword,
 * mostly because of strict ANSI C compliance or dumbness, we try to fall
 * back to either `__inline__' or `__inline'.
 * we define G_CAN_INLINE, if the compiler seems to be actually
 * *capable* to do function inlining, in which case inline function bodys
 * do make sense. we also define G_INLINE_FUNC to properly export the
 * function prototypes if no inlining can be performed.
 * we special case most of the stuff, so inline functions can have a normal
 * implementation by defining G_INLINE_FUNC to extern and G_CAN_INLINE to 1.
 */
#ifndef G_INLINE_FUNC
#  define G_CAN_INLINE 1
#endif
#ifdef G_HAVE_INLINE // compiler supports the __inline__ specifier
#  if defined (__GNUC__) && defined (__STRICT_ANSI__)
#    undef inline
#    define inline __inline__
#  endif
#else /* !G_HAVE_INLINE */
#  undef inline
#  if defined (G_HAVE___INLINE__)
#    define inline __inline__
#  else /* !inline && !__inline__ */
#    if defined (G_HAVE___INLINE) // compiler supports the __inline specifier
#      define inline __inline
#    else /* !inline && !__inline__ && !__inline */
#      define inline /* don't inline, then */
#      ifndef G_INLINE_FUNC
#    undef G_CAN_INLINE
#      endif
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
#ifndef G_INLINE_FUNC
#  ifdef __GNUC__
#    ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
#      define G_INLINE_FUNC extern inline
#    else
#      undef G_CAN_INLINE
#      define G_INLINE_FUNC extern
#    endif
#  else /* !__GNUC__ */
#    ifdef G_CAN_INLINE
#      define G_INLINE_FUNC static inline
#    else
#      define G_INLINE_FUNC extern
#    endif
#  endif /* !__GNUC__ */
#endif /* !G_INLINE_FUNC */
```

They seem to set `G_HAVE_INLINE` and `G_HAVE__INLINE_` in their very complicated configure file. Is there any way to do it in code without using autotools?

Comment: Just use `inline` and require that people use an *actual* current-standard-conforming C compiler to compile the code.

Comment: Should you need, like many people, to support non-compliant compilers, you can always give the user an include file and allow them to set it themselves.

Comment: At first we did the following. We checked if it is not `__GNUC__` and not `std99` then `#error.` But our boss didn't like it

Comment: If simply using `inline` is not sufficient, then you'll have to look at the set of compilers you are expected to support and work out how you tell them apart and what gyrations are needed to handle each.  But it would be far simpler to simply demand C99 or better support.  What is your fallback position if the compiler simply refuses to support `inline` with any technique?  And which compilers don't support `inline` in the first place?  It will probably end up being every bit as gnarly as using `autoconf` or equivalent.

Comment: Create a header file called `inline.h` or some such, include it in every source file, and do a configuration step which creates the file.  The options should be straightforward: do nothing, define `inline` as some misspelling of `inline`, or produce a compiler error (unless you're prepared to compile without inlined functions).

Comment: If `inline` is not supported we plan to provide only the function declaration and then  have its definition in a separate source file. I read the gcc docu and they seem to say that `inline` (without underscores) is supported starting from `std99` only

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "Just". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AC_C_INLINE`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/C-Compiler.html#AC_005fC_005fINLINE), with this autoconf macro, you can use `inline` in all cases, provided you include `config.h` (usual name for the autoconf generated header).

Comment: Yes, one can't avoid using autoconf here. But now the number and size of files generated by autotools are much greater than source files from the project itself!